# Share variables internally across functions

Tags: c, architecture, functional-programming, scope

Suppose I have a function like this:

```
static int init_processing(char *buf, FILE *stream, enum operationMode mode) {
    /* save index of `stream' in current operations */
    /* start processing */
    /* save some important variables for continue_processing */
    off_t position;
    enum operationMode _mode;
    return num_processing_operations_left;
}
```

.. that I would be calling occasionally. And I have another function that does the actual processing I want:

```
static int continue_processing(FILE *stream) {
    /* lookup the index of `stream' in current operations */
    /* do some stuff */
    /* save some static variables */
    static off_t left = position;
    static void *some_ptr;
    return --num_processing_operations_left;
}
```

I also have a cleaning function to invoke when finishing up a certain operation:

```
static int end_processing(FILE *stream) {
    /* check */
    if (num_processing_operations_left)
        return 1;
    /* clean everything */
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, this related functions technique is very familiar that it is used by the standard library itself (e.g [*malloc*, *free*, *realloc*], [*fdopen*, *fopen*, *fclose*]).

What I want to achieve here, is how to share some variables across a bunch of functions ?
I thought of two solutions:

- Put each set of functions in a file of their own, providing static variables valid only for the file itself.
- Use only one function that takes an extra enum parameter as a mode and structure the function accordingly.

But these solutions aren't actually *solutions*, they're just workarounds to cope with the problem. So, is there any standard technique to share variables among functions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a context structure keeping all you need:

```
struct Context
{
  FILE * stream;
  off_t position;
  unsigned num_processing_operations_left;
  /* define some more important variables */
}
```

and pass it to all functions in question:

```
static int init_processing(struct Context * pctx, char *buf, enum operationMode mode);
static int continue_processing(struct Context * pctx);
static int end_processing(struct Context * pctx);

int main(void)
{
  struct Context ctx = {0};

  /* init ctx here */

  int result = init_processing(&ctx, ...);

  ...

  result = continue_processing(&ctx);

  ...

  result = end_processing(&ctx);

  ...
}
```

Comment: That seems to be a reasonable solution. Are there any libraries known to use this style ?

Comment: The buffered file I/O API (`fopen()`, `fread()`, `fwrite()`, `fclose()` and friends) uses exactly this approach. The "context" structure used is `FILE`. @AmrAyman